# Add custom actions to Django admin home page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm looking to add a [custom action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) for a django reusable app I'm designing, however rather than being specific to a single model, I want to place a link to the action on the front page of the admin site.

Is it easily possible to add links or site-wide actions to the home page in Django, or is it a matter of overriding templates?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it easily possible to add links or site-wide actions to the home page in Django ...

links yes, Note sure what site-wide actions means.

> or is it a matter of overriding templates?

Yep, it's a matter of overriding templates (AFAIK). But easy and overriding templates are not mutually exclusive.

For anyone who got here because they just want the easy ~standard way to actually "add custom actions [i.e. links] to Django home page" (tested in django 1.9):

Given a django project called 'myproj' and your current working dir is the project dir:

```
mkdir -p myproj/templates/admin/
edit myproj/templates/admin/index.html
```

Start with the following in `index.html` template and your site will be unchanged. Then fiddle about putting links in those blocks to suit your need.

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create custom action method and call in actions list.

```
 class YourCustomClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model: YourModel
        actions = ['make_active', 'make_inactive',]

        def make_active(self, request, queryset):
            '''make_active from action'''
            queryset.update(is_active=True)
        make_active.short_description = "Make selected users as Active"

        def make_inactive(self, request, queryset):
            '''make_inactive from action'''
            queryset.update(is_active=False)
        make_inactive.short_description = "Make selected users as Inactive"
```